# Cumulative distribution function and inverse transform method.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

maybe my question is not very clever, anyway I hope that someone will help me to better understand this part of probability theory, subject which is almost completely new for me. 
My problem deals with an observation related to the transformation of random variables through the inverse transform method. 
Indeed, before starting the proof of the proposition, it can be noticed that:

[image] Indeed,
[image]

What makes me confused is the last statement. Does this mean that a cumulative distribution function of a random varible has its own cumulative distribution function? Indeed, the proposition above doesn't refer to the cdf of X, but to the cdf of F(X), (which is the cdf of X). 
My intuition is that the cdf of a random variable is a random variable itself, but I can't find a statement like this anywhere. If this is true, then it's clear that any cdf is distributed as a uniform and I can easily apply the quantile method to sample from any distribution. If it is not, what's wrong in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a random variable and $f$ is any function, then $f(X)$ is again a random variable (yes?). This must be immediate/clear.

Now, take $F$ in place of this random $f$, where $F$ denotes the cdf of $X$, and you have that $F(X)$ is again a random variable, but now you can also determine the exact distribution of the random variable $F(X)$ which is, for any $X$, the uniform distribution.

So, your intuition seems correct to me.

Comment: Only under the assumption that $X$ is atomless.